# Sharepoint 2013 foundation is not crawling word 2007 documents, how to fix?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, office, crawl

I am using SharePoint 2013 Foundation. I have many documents in my portal. Some are from office 2007, or 2010 or 2013. I see that my crawler is crawling office 2010 and 2013 documents, but NOT 2007. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: did you see any error in crawl logs?

Comment: When I open the file and click on convert and save it back to  sharepoint it is working. How can I fix this for a bulk word 2007 files?